# Why are my navigation's sub-menus changing widths and how do I fix it?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, submenu

Whenever I open up a submenu or subsubmenu in my navigation, the width of the parent menu changes. What am I doing wrong here; how do I prevent that? **My goal was to have the sub-menus have a min-width equal to the menu above it.** Also, why isn't the bottom border lining up properly on some menu items, but looks great on others? I need this menu to look nice and polished before I show it off to the client. This just won't do.

My HTML:

```
<div id="navigation-wrapper">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li class="n1">
                <a href="PrimaryLink">Main Link</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                        <ul class="subsub">
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="n2">
                <a href="PrimaryLink">Main Link</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                        <ul class="subsub">
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="n3">
                <a href="PrimaryLink">Main Link</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                        <ul class="subsub">
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="n4">
                <a href="PrimaryLink">Main Link</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                        <ul class="subsub">
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="n5">
                <a href="PrimaryLink">Main Link</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="SecondaryLink">Secondary Link</a>
                        <ul class="subsub">
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                            <li><a href="TertiaryLink">Tertiary Link</a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
/* ----------------------------
NAVIGATION 
------------------------------*/
#navigation-wrapper {
    width: 100%; 
    background: #f6f6f6 url(../images/sprites_bgs.png) repeat-x top; 
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
#navigation {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border: 0px solid #9C0;
    height: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#nav,
#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#nav {
    float: left;
}

#nav > li {
    float: left;
    height: 64px;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav > li > a {
    line-height: 64px;
    text-align: center;
}
.n1 { width: 219px; }
.n2 { width: 228px; }
.n3 { width: 94px; }
.n4 { width: 154px; }
.n5 { width: 255px; }
#nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
#nav li:hover ul.noJS {
    display: block; 
}

/* Main menu
--------------*/
#nav {
/* font-family: Arial; */
    font-size: 16px; /* 12px */
    background: transparent; /* #2f8be8 */
}
#nav > li > a {
    color: #555; /* #fff */
    font-weight: 700;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #fff;
}
#nav > li:hover > a {
    background: #00275E;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
}
#nav > li > a.last {
    border-right: 0;
}

/* Submenu
-----------*/
#nav ul {
    background: #00275E;
    width:auto;
}
#nav ul > li {
    max-height: 37px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#nav ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px; /* 12px */
    padding: .6em .6em;
}
#nav ul li:hover a {
    background: #0085BD;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Sub-submenu
-----------*/
#nav ul li > ul {
    left: -99999em;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#nav > li:hover > ul {
    left: auto;
}
#nav > li li:hover > ul {
    bottom: 37px;
    left: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#nav > li li:hover > ul a {
    background: #00275E;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav > li li:hover > ul a:hover {
    background: #0085BD;
    color: #fff;
}

/* arrow hover styling */
#nav ul li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before { 
    content: "";
    float: right;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    width: 0;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
}
#nav li li > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
    border-left-color: #fff;
    margin: -5px 0 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Solved the second question with the bottom borders, but I'm still looking for ways to keep the menu width from jumping all around.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my...

```
#nav ul > li {
    max-height: 37px;
}
```

...needed to be...

```
#nav ul > li {
    height: 37px;
}
```

...in order to keep the bottom borders lined up.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #141414;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0fa1e0;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #141414;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  font-size: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a,
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  background: #070707;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0fa1e0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
  font-size: 11px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #0a6d98;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu" class="align-center">
  <ul>
     <li class="active has-sub"><a href="#" target="_blank"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-chain"></i> Main Link</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-chain"></i> Main Link</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-chain"></i> Main Link</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-chain"></i> Main Link</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-chain"></i> Main Link</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a></li>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Secondary Link</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a></li>
                 <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Tertiary Link</span></a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href="#"><span>Test</span></a></li>
                       <li><a href="#"><span>Test</span></a></li>
                       <li><a href="#"><span>Test</span></a></li>
                       <li><a href="#"><span>Test</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```